Can not add any data into aiosqlite database table
I am creating a bot using aiogram library. I need to store users. I decided not to use sqlite3 but aiosqlite, because it is asynchronous. Here's the code for the handler:
@all_router.message(Command('start'))
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    load_dotenv()
    kb = None
    if message.from_user.id == int(os.getenv('ADMIN_ID')):
       kb = admin_keyboard
    else: 
       kb = reply_menu_keyboard
       users = Users()
       await users.add_user(message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer(await start_text(message.from_user.username), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=kb)

And the code for the db method:
    async def start(self) -> None:
        async with aiosql.connect(self.path) as con:
            request = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                          user_telegram_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                          status TEXT NOT NULL)'''
            await con.execute(request)

    async def add_user(self, uid: int) -> None:
        '''The method adds a user into the table'''
        await self.start()
        async with aiosql.connect(self.path) as con:
            cursor = await con.cursor()
            request = 'INSERT INTO users(user_telegram_id, status) VALUES(?, ?)'
            await cursor.execute(request, (uid, 'member'))

However, whenever I run /start nothing happens! It does not add anything into the table and shows no error. I don't know what may be wrong.
I've been using sqlite3 for a while now, but never have I faced such an issue. I really need your help, the mistake might well be very silly.

use asyncpg its for postgresql database

@Khaliknazar that's not helpful. The db has to be temporary, and for this purpose aiosqlite is more suitable

then commit your query

You should commit every query like this
con.commit()

It lets a user permanently save all the changes made in the transaction of a database or table.

Oh gosh, that works. But in sqlite3 you didn't need to commit anything if you use cursor to execute, to the connection itself, isn't it? That's why I struggled to solve this issue. Thank you very much!

One more question, if you could help me. I have a lot of methods in a database (about 15-20), and I know that connecting to a database in each of them (writing async with aiosql.connect(self.path) ) is not a very good practice. How can I do this another way?

use sessions, sqlalchemy orm supports session and you can use sqlite and sqlalchemy orm with sessions
